# Can I omit type in generics? - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, dagger-2

If I have a following interface:

```
interface BaseDataRemote<T, in Params> {
    fun getData(params: Params? = null): Single<T>
}
```

Would it be possible have implementation of this interface that does not take Params?
To have effectively something like:

```
interface BaseDataRemote<T> {
    fun getData(): Single<T>
}
```

Implementation is as follows:

```
class RemoteSellerDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val sellerApi: SellerApi,
    @Named("LANG") private val lang: String
) : BaseDataRemote<SellerEntity, Nothing> {
    override fun getData(params: Nothing?): Single<SellerEntity> {
        return sellerApi.getSeller(lang).map { it.fromApiEntity() }
    }
}
```

I use Dagger 2 to module to bind this implementation:

```
@Module
internal interface RemoteModule {

    @Binds
    @CoreScope
    fun bindsSellerRemote(remoteSellerDataSource: RemoteSellerDataSource): BaseDataRemote<SellerEntity, Nothing>
}
```

I tried using `Nothing` as second type parameter, but it does not seem to work
(I'm getting `required: class or interface without bounds` error
Full error message:

```
RemoteSellerDataSource.java:6: error: unexpected type
public final class RemoteSellerDataSource implements com.bigchangedev.stamps.business.sdk.data.base.data.BaseDataRemote<SellerEntity, ?> {
                                                                                                                       ^
  required: class or interface without bounds
  found:?
```

Thanks.

Comment: `Nothing` should be the way to go, can you show the code that gives you the error you mention?

Comment: Is `RemoteSellerDataSource` defined in a Java file? Why does the error mention `RemoteSellerDataSource.java`?

Comment: It defined in Kotlin, but it gets converted to java, because Dagger 2 works with java files

Comment: I wonder if this happens because there is no 'Nothnig' type in java

Comment: It might be a limitation of Dagger then. In that case, a workaround would be to use `Unit` instead of `Nothing`, which Dagger will most likely convert to `Void` in this case. This is not great for your types, though. You can also try `@JvmSuppressWildcards` on your generic type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: the original answer was a pure Kotlin answer because the OP didn't mention Dagger.

Using `Nothing` is correct and works in pure Kotlin. However, Dagger seems to convert your code to Java, and in doing so it uses wildcards for the generics (which it doesn't like because it wants exact type matches). To avoid this issue, you can try using `@JvmSuppressWildcards` on your generic type parameters:

```kotlin
class RemoteSellerDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val sellerApi: SellerApi,
    @Named("LANG") private val lang: String
) : BaseDataRemote<SellerEntity, @JvmSuppressWildcards Nothing> {
    override fun getData(params: Nothing?): Single<SellerEntity> {
        return sellerApi.getSeller(lang).map { it.fromApiEntity() }
    }
}
```

Although I'm not sure what will happen in Java with `Nothing` in that case. I guess this should have the same effect on the Java code as removing the `in` variance for the second type param in the interface declaration, but without weakening your Kotlin types.

Another workaround would be to use `Unit` instead of `Nothing`, which Dagger will most likely convert to `Void` in this case. This is not great for your types, though.

---

**Original answer:**

You can technically already call `getData()` without arguments thanks to the default value. An implementation that doesn't care about the `params` argument can simply expect null all the time.

The Kotlin type that only contains `null` and no other value is technically `Nothing?`, and since `getData` is defined with `Params?` (note the `?`) as input, it should be correct to specify `Nothing` (even without `?`) as second type argument. So you should be able to define an implementation like this:

```kotlin
interface BaseDataRemote<T, in Params> {
    fun getData(params: Params? = null): Single<T>
}

class ImplementationWithoutParams<T> : BaseDataRemote<T, Nothing> {
    override fun getData(params: Nothing?): Single<T> {
        // params will always be null here
    }
}
```

To avoid confusion for the users, this implementation may additionally provide a `getData()` method without arguments at all:

```kotlin
class ImplementationWithoutParams<T> : BaseDataRemote<T, Nothing> {
    override fun getData(params: Nothing?): Single<T> = getData()

    fun getData(): Single<T> {
        TODO("implementation")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey. One thing that might be important is that I use Dagger to bind implementation. I added implementation in description...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it matters. What exactly fails in your case? Maybe you can update the question with additional information about how you use Dagger to instantiate this, and where/when you get errors

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey I added more details in description

Comment: Thanks @Joffrey. `@JvmSuppressWildcards` did now  work for me, but Unit worked perfectly. I appreciate your help. Thank you.